# How to zgrep multiple string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am trying to zgrep multiple strings with the code below, but if I omit one of the parameter it spools a lot of un-matching files. But, I i enter all the 5 strings it works correctly. How can I zgrep any number of strings even if its just 3 of 5.

```
echo "Enter string 1: "
read isdn1
echo "Enter string 2: "
read isdn2
echo "Enter string 3: "
read isdn3
echo "Enter string 4: "
read isdn4
echo "Enter string 5: "
read isdn5

for host in $(cat host.txt); do ssh "$host" "cd /onip/cdr/output/snapshot/normal/backup && zgrep '$isdn1\|$isdn2\|$isdn3\|$isdn4\|$isdn5' xyz_shot*"
```

Comment: Please read [To read lines rather than words, pipe/redirect to a 'while read' loop.](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2013)

Answer (score 0):

Since you omit some values, your expression becomes

```
e1|e2||e4|e5
```

The empty expression in the middle makes everything match.

Note sure it is the most optimal method but I would remove the double pipe chars with a `sed` first:

```
e=`echo $isdn1|$isdn2|$isdn3|$isdn4|$isdn5 |  sed 's/|\+/|/g'`
```

then

```
for host in $(cat host.txt); do ssh "$host" "cd /onip/cdr/output/snapshot/normal/backup && zgrep \"$e\" xyz_shot*"
```

(note that the escaping of the pipe chars is gone, but it's not necessary here)

Comment: Getting error "command not found" --- e=$(echo $isdn1|$isdn2|$isdn3|$isdn4|$isdn5 |  sed 's/|\+/|/g') and my script still get the same wrong output

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
echo "Enter string 1: "
read isdn1
echo "Enter string 2: "
read isdn2
echo "Enter string 3: "
read isdn3
echo "Enter string 4: "
read isdn4
echo "Enter string 5: "
read isdn5

grep_str=`echo "$isdn1|$isdn2|$isdn3|$isdn4|$isdn5"|perl -pe 's/\|\||\|$//'`
for host in $(cat host.txt); do ssh "$host" "cd /onip/cdr/output/snapshot/normal/backup && zgrep '$grep_str' xyz_shot*"
```

Comment: Not getting any output at all from this, just blank